# What makes a difference if the ruler is marked?

Tags: geometric-construction

The classical straightedge and compass construction problems, i.e. squaring the circle, devising a trisecting algorithm for a generic angle, doubling the cube, are they indeed answered in the positive, should the ruler be marked? Why, a marked ruler marks constructible lengths along it, and the compass could draw arcs of constructible radius already, ain't so? I don't see why marked rulers are an advantage. The sources stating so apparently renders this as a most obvious fact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Traditionally a "marked ruler" has exactly two marks on it, at a distance we can choose to call $1$. The marks on the ruler are supposed to let you do the following

> Given a point $A$ and lines $l$, $m$, construct a line through $A$ such that its intersections with $l$ and $m$ are exactly $1$ unit apart.

To do this, imagine sliding *one* mark on the ruler along line $l$ with one hand while keeping the ruler snug against a pin at point $A$ with the other hand. When you see the *other* mark pass line $m$, stop and draw a line along the ruler.

In variants of this task, the role of $l$ and/or $m$ may be played by circular arcs.

This is known as a [neusis construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neusis_construction), and is what you can't do in general with an unmarked straightedge. It is not the fact that your two intersection points are a known distance apart, but the fact that you can choose *both* intersection at once such that the resulting line goes through $A$.

With a marked ruler and neusis, you can trisect angles and double cubes (or in general extract cube roots), but the constructible points will still all have **algebraic** coordinates, so you *can't* square the circle that way.

Comment: Thanks, finally I understood what's the essence  of marked rulers!